# Increase neo4j startup

Tags: neo4j, timeout, startup

I am trying to increase the neo4j statup timeout but I didn't find the configuration to do so. I increased the timeout in neo4j daemon but it didn't change the startup timeout. Mt graph is very large(140GB) and 120 second is probably is not enough.

I have neo4j 2.1.7 installed on Ubuntu 12.04

Error:

```
../bin/neo4j start
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
Starting Neo4j Server...process [7886]... waiting for server to be ready...2015-02-22 16:54:10.044+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2015-02-22 16:54:10.044+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
......................................................................................................................2015-02-22 16:56:11.610+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
2015-02-22 16:56:11.610+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
 Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout=0` to the file below and it did it. I start neo4j and after 20 minutes, it recovered and start.

```
neo4j-server.properties
```

Comment: Strange, i tried other tactics like increasing limit, start-no-wait, but this one did the trick. Also I want to point that even combination of this trick and starting neo4j as root user works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a crash before so that it has to check for recovery?

Did you check the logs as it states? Best `data/graph.db/messages.log` and `data/logs/neo4j.log`

You can also start `neo4j console` then it will run in foreground mode and take as long as it takes.

Comment: I tried neo4j console but it behave the same way, and shot itself after 120s with error:   ./neo4j console
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
Using additional JVM arguments:.......
2015-02-22 22:34:42.186+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1


2015-02-22 22:36:42.295+0000 INFO  [AP  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `neo4j start-no-wait` instead of `neo4j start` in case you don't want to do a config change.